# Place icon on an element that is simply text

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can't believe how much I'm struggling with this simple task.  What is the correct way to place a jQuery Mobile data-icon on an element that the user does not interact with?  What if I want a paragraph that just displays a message to the user like "No suitable lots were found" and I want that element to have the "info" icon?

I know this won't do it, but something like:

```
<p data-role="content" data-icon="info" class="my-message-block">No suitable lots were found</p>
```

Not a link.  Not a button or checkbox or ....  Just a plain old box displaying a message?  All examples I see are an interactive element and not a static element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by adding a span with some CSS as follows:

```
<p data-role="content" class="my-message-block"><span class="ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>No suitable lots were found</p>
```

Then the `inlineIcon` class has these rules to place the icon:

```
.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

The right margin controls the space between the icon and the text.

If you prefer a black icon with no gray disk behind it:

```
<p class="my-message-block"><span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>No suitable lots were found</p>

.inlineIconNoDisk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.inlineIconNoDisk:after {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

`ui-alt-icon` on the span changes the icon color and `background-color: transparent;` on the :after pseudo element hides the disk.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fzahxxtu/2/)**